# Link in horizontal menu

Tags: category, url-rewrite, menu

I added a link in the horizontal menu using subcategories and url rewrite. It works using this method http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html#gref

Trying to add a second link there I had a different result with the same procedure.

In **Url rewrite**, in the **Request Path** I inserted the name of the page ("*assistance*") but there's no such page in the results.

The page is regularly published in CMS under url key "*assistance*"

How to find the page in URL rewrite menu?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you please describe what you expect and what doesn't work as expected? Is the link broken? The link works (no 404) but shows wrong content? Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION!

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your post.
While creating a CMS page you have to set an url for it.
That's it. After creating a CMS page you can call it by that link.
The url rewrite has nothing to do with your CMS page so please delete that rewrite you have choosen and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't there anymore.

Following the **whole procedure** published on that link the items is regularly there in the menu and the redirect is working to the correct page.

I need to pay attention to **index management**. After a reindexing those links in horizontal menu didn't work anymore